# Umlauts not beeing displayed properly in symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.5

Im having the following problem.
If I try to use this code

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('code', 'integer', array(
            'attr' => array('class' => 'login-input')
        ))
        ->add('einlösen', 'submit', array(
            'attr' => array('class' => 'login-submit')
        ))
        ->getForm();
```

my browser doesnt show the ö in einlösen.
If i remove the class attr it works.
I thought this might be a css issue but the problem seems to be with symfony, since there
is no matter what class I use the ö always gets mangled.

Another thing I realized is that if I do a cache clear the ö is there but as soon as i press the button once and reload the page its not showing up properly again.

Comment: Can't you add a label to this field? Does your entity property has also an umlaut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the label option:

```
$this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('submit', 'submit', array(
        'label' => 'einlösen',
        'attr' => array('class' => 'login-submit')
    ))
```

As an alternative you can set/overwrite the label in twig:

```
{{ form_widget(form.submit, { 'label': 'einlösen' }) }}
```

Comment: As he said in response to my comment, it's a button, it won't help him.

Comment: hmm the submitType has a label though... but well I generally  would recommend switching language of the code to english and move definition of (german) labels to the frontend / translation files.

Comment: it seems to work this way.
Sorry Veve I misunderstood you there.